# Searching A Nested List

Tags: python

So I've been given a large text file with an assortment . The first thing I did was iterate over it and add it to a list so that each line is an element. I then made it so that the line could be indexed into. See code below.

```
def main():
   f = open("/usr/local/doc/FEguide.txt", "r")
   full = list()
   companies= list()
   for line in f:
      line = line.split(",")
      full.append(line[1:])
```

A line from the opened file is in this format. (The 1: slice is in order to omit the useless first element in the text line, not shown below)

Now I need to make it so that the user can enter the search term of an Automaker or Type (ie. Standard SUV). My hunch is that I need to make a list of just automakers (which could be done with some kind of slice) and then a list of (all the types) and then have this call the entire line if true. I'm having trouble actually implementing that.

Comment: You should look into [`dict`ionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [the `csv` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

you could use zip and dict.

assuming you have this file:

```
General Motors,Chevrolet,K1500 TAHOE 4WD,2900
General Motors,Chevrolet,TRAVERSE AWD,2750
Chrysler Group LLC,Dodge,Durango AWD,2750   
Chrysler Group LLC,Dodge,Durango AWD,3400
Ford Motor Company,Ford,Expedition 4WD,3100
Ford Motor Company,Ford,EXPLORER AWD,275
```

first define how your header should looks like:

...cars.py...

```
import sys

cars_list = []
# header list
headers = ['company', 'Line', 'Type', 'Annual Cost']

with open('/home/ajava/tst.txt') as file:
    # you should maybe check if both zip matrixs have the same size!!
    for line in file:
        zipped_list = zip(headers,line.strip().split(','))

        #create a dictionary of zipped-tuples and append it to the car_list
        cars_list.append(dict(zipped_list))

# printing results
print("\t".join(headers))
for item in cars_list:
    print("{company}\t{line}\t{type}\t{annual cost}".format(**item))
```

your output should looks like that:

```
  company   line    type    annual cost
  General Motors    Chevrolet   K1500 TAHOE 4WD 2900
  General Motors    Chevrolet   TRAVERSE AWD    2750
  Chrysler Group LLC    Dodge   Durango AWD 2750
  Chrysler Group LLC    Dodge   Durango AWD 3400
  Ford Motor Company    Ford    Expedition 4WD  3100
  Ford Motor Company    Ford    EXPLORER AWD    275
```

this is ofcourse just a simple example how you could do that with no extra libs.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to reinvent the wheel, unless this is a programming assignment. I'll leave the command-line interactions up to you, but the basic functionality is here using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('FEguid.txt')

print '----------------------------'
print 'All companies sorted:'
print df.sort('Company').Company
print '----------------------------'
print 'All Dodge models:'
print df[df['Line'] == 'Dodge']
print '----------------------------'
print 'Mean MPG and annual cost per company'
print df.groupby('Company').mean()
print '----------------------------'
print 'Mean MPG and annual cost per car type'
print df.groupby('Type').mean()
```

**Output:**

```
----------------------------
All companies sorted:
2    Chrysler Group LLC
3    Chrysler Group LLC
4    Ford Motor Company
5    Ford Motor Company
1        General Motors
0        General Motors
Name: Company, dtype: object
----------------------------
All Dodge models:
              Company   Line         Type  MPG  Annual Cost          Category
2  Chrysler Group LLC  Dodge  Durango AWD   19         2750  Standard SUV 4WD
3  Chrysler Group LLC  Dodge  Durango AWD   16         3400  Standard SUV 4WD
----------------------------
Mean MPG and annual cost per company
                     MPG  Annual Cost
Company
Chrysler Group LLC  17.5         3075
Ford Motor Company  18.0         2925
General Motors      18.5         2825
----------------------------
Mean MPG and annual cost per car type
                  MPG  Annual Cost
Type
Durango AWD      17.5         3075
EXPLORER AWD     19.0         2750
Expedition 4WD   17.0         3100
K1500 TAHOE 4WD  18.0         2900
TRAVERSE AWD     19.0         2750
```